# Recursive Function named Power

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, recursion

I'm having a bit of trouble with my code. When I run the code an error for line 8 occurs and says the `power` is not defined. I'm having trouble understanding because I thought that is was defined already. Can someone show me where I went wrong or what I need to do for `power` to be defined because I can't see it.

```
#This program has on file containing a main function and a recursive function named power which recursively calculates the value of the power and then returns it.

def main():
    base = int(input('Enter an integer for the base: '))
    expon = int(input('Enter and integer for the exponent: '))

answer = power(base, expon)

print('The base you entered is ', base)
print('The exponent you entered is ', expon)
print(base, 'to the power of', expon, 'equals', answer)

def power(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return 1
    if y >= 1:
        return x * power(x, y-1)

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused because this line which *uses* `power`:

```
answer = power(base, expon)
```

comes before these lines which *define* `power`:

```
def power(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return 1
    if y >= 1:
        return x * power(x, y-1)
```

To fix this, you'll need to define `power` before you use it.

**Edit -** Here's how I would rearrange the code:

```
def power(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return 1
    if y >= 1:
        return x * power(x, y-1)

base = int(input('Enter an integer for the base: '))
expon = int(input('Enter and integer for the exponent: '))
answer = power(base, expon)

print('The base you entered is ', base)
print('The exponent you entered is ', expon)
print(base, 'to the power of', expon, 'equals', answer)
```

Comment: I fixed that but now the program is saying that 'base' is not defined... how is that?

Comment: The same reasoning applies. Ensure that `base` is defined (assigned to) before you attempt to use its value.

Comment: Like base = base? But that would be placed before the print statement in the main function? Because the user is supposed to input a number.

Comment: That's the point: have the user input the number to assign to `base` *before* you use `base`.

Comment: I thought I did though... Sorry if I'm being a pain I'm just trying to understand this better. Can you give a random example?

Comment: Oh, I understand but what if the code has to have a main function?

Comment: @Ashley I'm not sure why that would be the case, but you would just add the main function in a way that you don't break something. Chronological ordering is key to all programming.

Comment: What do you mean by adding the main function in a way that doesn't break something? I thought the main function is always first and I'd have to call it at the end.

Comment: @Ashley I don't believe that's the case.

Comment: Oh, well what would the code look like if it had both the main function and this recursion power function? Just for my own personal knowledge. I'm curious.

Comment: @Ashley The code can look like anything you want it to. There are infinitely many ways to write a program that does any given thing.

Comment: Ahh, well how/where would you add the main function into this particular code then? While still ensuring that it Runs properly.

Comment: @Ashley As I said, it could be inserted anywhere, as long as said insertion is done in such a way that the code still works. There are infinitely many ways to do that. Again, I don't see much point in doing that when it's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Python is an interpreted language, when you run the script, it runs the script line by line , so if you are going to use any variable or functions in your script, you should have defined (or imported its definition from some library or another script) prior to using it. It is not like other compiled languages (like Java).